# how to switch Visual-Studio 2010 into c++11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm new in programming in c++ and I want to try c++11 new features.

So what am I asking for is how can I switch visual-studio 2010 to be able to compile c++11 sources?

Comment: It supports *some* C++11 features, and that's it. There is no switch.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to this table: [C++0x Core Language Features In VC10: The Table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx). Just use those in your code.

Answer (score 4):

There is no switch; VC10 (and VC12) will always compile code that conforms to the parts of C++11 that they support. Which of course is not *all* of it.

Comment: It's VC11 and VS2012, just to confuse us.

Comment: thanks for answer. So for example is chaining contructor supported by vc10??