# Debug assertion failure while using strftime

Tags: c, datetime, strftime

My code is below,

```
time_t t;
struct tm tm;
struct tm * tmp;
time( &t ); 
tmp = gmtime(&t);

char buf[100];
strftime(buf, 42, "%F", tmp); // assertion failure
```

It says `expression:("Invalid format directive",0). I wanted to convert the time to Short YYYY-MM-DD date, equivalent to %Y-%m-%d format.

Same thing happens when I try this,

```
const char* fmt = "%a, %d %b %y %T %z";

if (strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, tmp) == 0) // assertion failure
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

Comment: %F, %T and %z are C99/C++11. Are you compiling as c99 or c++11, or as something else?

Comment: How do I find that out? Thanks.

Comment: What command are you running to compile it?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010. Its a windows console application. I just press Ctrl+ F5.

Comment: No experience with visual studio, but somewhere in the project settings you should be able to set compiler options. One of them will be the language you're using. It's also possible that you may need to update to a later version of the IDE.

Comment: Oh, scratch that, visual studio supports part of the spec and has no options http://stackoverflow.com/q/11276716/1180785 You'll need to update your IDE, switch to a different IDE, or simply avoid the newer formatting options (and probably quite a few other features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%F`, `%T` and `%z` were introduced by C99, and only came to C++ in C++11. From the comments on your question, it appears you're using Microsoft's partial implementation of C++11 in VisualStudio 2010. Unfortunately your only options are:

- update your IDE (I don't know if later versions support this, but I'd imagine they do)
- switch to a different IDE (anything which uses GCC for its compiler will certainly support this)
- avoid using the newer formatting flags (you can find a list here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/ anything yellow is new)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;
    struct tm * tmp;
    time( &t ); 
    tmp = gmtime(&t);

    const char* fmt = "%a, %d %b %y %T %z";
    char buf[100];
    if (strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, tmp) == 0) // assertion failure
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
        return 1; 
    }
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Fri, 23 May 14 06:48:27 +0000
```